# Using the Haml object reference e.g. %div[@user]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Haml has a nice feature called [Object reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#object_reference_) where I can do something like this:

```
%div[user]= user.name
```

And it generates something like this:

```
<div id="user_42" class="user">Billy</div>
```

Sometimes, I want to create an anchor to that element, like this:

```
<a href="#user_42">Link to Billy</a>
```

How do I do that in Haml? Is there an easier way than this?:

```
%a{ :href=> "#user_#{user.id} } Link to Billy
```

Edit: Could be done with the automatically-included [Haml helpers](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method)?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I would advise staying away from the Haml helpers. They quickly get very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this that I know of. I'd probably create a helper method if it's something you'll be doing a lot.

```
def anchor_to(link_text, object)
  link_to(link_text, "##{object.class.name.underscore}_#{object.id}")
end
```

You could make the method more complex if you need to handle more cases (passing along options to link_to, etc.) but something simple like that would clean it up some. Generating the link becomes:

```
= anchor_to("Link to Billy", @user)
```

If you want to use Haml helpers, you could do something very similar (but much more confusing):

```
def anchor_to(link_text, object)
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :a, 'Link to Billy', href: "##{object.class.name.underscore}_#{object.id}"
  end
end
```

Although, be warned that the `underscore` method won't be available if you're doing this outside of Rails (which is the only reason I can think of for avoiding the link_to helper).